# Suse Linux docker file

Tags: docker, suse, sles, zypper

I have a suse `linux 12 ec2` instance. I have activated a image `sles11sp3-docker-image` using sledocker. In the Dockerfile when I try to install `ibm java 1.6` using 
RUN zypper in `java-1_6_0-ibm`, I get following error .

> Refreshing service 'container-suseconnect'.
>   Problem retrieving the repository index file for service 'container-suseconnect':
>   [|] 
>   Skipping service 'container-suseconnect' because of the above error.
>   Warning: No repositories defined. Operating only with the installed resolvables. Nothing can be installed.
>   Loading repository data...
>   Reading installed packages...
>   'java-1_6_0-ibm' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
>   Resolving package dependencies...
>   No provider of 'java-1_6_0-ibm' found.
>
> Nothing to do.
>   The command '/bin/sh -c zypper in java-1_6_0-ibm' returned a non-zero code: 104

Please help

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs (https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles-12/singlehtml/dockerquick/dockerquick.html), running `zypper ref -s` only gets you repo URLs with 12 hour tokens.  Moreover, this command only appears to work while running in Docker on a SLES12 host.

Once I push the image to a repo and run it on another host, `zypper ref -s` no longer works (same error as yours).  I'm basically stuck pre-installing all the base stuff before I publish the image.